# Find the max and min values of a function using python

Tags: python, max, min

Write a function `maxmin(f, a, b, n=1000)` for finding the maximum
and minimum values of a mathematical function `f(x)` in the interval
between `a` and `b`. The following test program

```
from math import cos, pi
print maxmin(cos, -pi/2, 2*pi, 100001)
```

should write out

```
(1.0, -1.0).
```

The `maxmin` function can compute a set of `n` uniformly spaced coordinates
between `a` and `b` stored in a list `x`, then compute `f` at the
points in `x` and store the values in another list `y`. The Python functions
`max(y)` and `min(y)` return the maximum and minimum values in the
list `y`, respectively.

I tried using

```
from math import cos, pi
import numpy

def maxmin(f, a, b, n=1000):
    x = (f(i) for i in numpy.linspace(a, b, n))
    #print x
    maximum = max(x==2)
    minimum = min(x==0)
    return maximum, minimum

print maxmin(cos, -pi/2, 2*pi, 100001)
```

But it doesn't run properly. When i mean it doesn't work properly i doesn't give me the max and min that i should be getting which (1.0, -1.0).
 This is the error i get

```
minimum = min(x)
ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence
>>>
```

I'm confused what sequence it wants

Comment: what is `numpy.linespace`?

Comment: When you say "*it doesn't run properly*", what do you mean? Please [edit] your question to include the **complete** output of the program, including the full text of any errors you are getting.

Comment: I think you meant `numpy.linspace`, Mitch?

Comment: In your lines `maximum = max(x)` and `minimum = min(x)`, are you trying to use the built-in `max` and `min` functions, or those from numpy? This is why `from module import *` is not a great idea - you get namespace collisions, and unexpected behavior. Try `import numpy as np` instead, then explicitly call the functions you want.

Comment: `import numpy ` then your function returns `(1.0, -1.0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted will give you a `NameError: global name 'numpy' is not defined` because of the way you are importing stuff.  Instead of doing

```
from numpy import *
```

just do

```
import numpy
```

Also, the function in numpy is called `linspace`, not `linespace`.  If you change those two things it will work, but there are still other problems.

You seem not to understand how Python's imports work.  That's the root of the problem here.  Whenever you type `from numpy import *`, Python *finds* numpy and puts all the stuff defined in numpy into your current file.  So you can't refer to stuff in numpy as `numpy.linspace`, `numpy.sin`, or whatever.  You just refer to them as `linspace` and `sin`.

Comment: can you help me with the other problems.. I'm sorry i'm not very good at programming at all.  My teacher just embarrasses us if we ask questions and insults our intelligence in class so no one asks questions.

Comment: I think that even if the OP fixes this, they need to use a list comprehension for the definition of `x` instead of a generator.  That's what the empty sequence error is from.  None of the problems you point out would have caused that particular `ValueError`.

Comment: @Mitch If this didn't answer all your questions, why accept it?

Comment: @SethMMorton This *did* answer the version of the question that was up when I answered it.  Then the OP changed the `x` to a generator expression, and used `max` and `min` in the weird way it's being used now, FWIW.

Comment: Ah, I was unawares of that.  In that case, that is poor etiquette on the part of the OP.  @Mitch, if you have a new question, post it as a new question.  Otherwise, people like me might accuse someone of not answering the question correctly.

Comment: I'd like to retract my downvote now, but it won't let me because it's been too long... if you edit this somehow I can, though.

Comment: No worries, @SethMMorton.  I appreciate the consideration though.